# Validate Fired Events in 'Container Component' in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to adopt the philosophy of performing all operations in 'Container Component' (aka smart component) & then just passing data on to the 'Presentation Components'.

I am stuck at this point, where I need to validate the user action (event fired) before I dispatch the action to the `Reducer`. The way I want to do this is by validating the event in the function inside 'mapDispatchToProps'.

The code looks like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ oneState, twoState }) => {
    return({
        oneState : oneState,
        twoState : twoState
    });
};

 const mapDispatchToProps = ( dispatch ) => {
    return({
        dispatchOneAction : () => {
    // do the validation here. The validation requires access to 
    // the 'oneState' obj above in the 'mapStateToProps'
        }
    });
 };

const C_Element = connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )( Ele );
```

My question is, is it possible? Or must I perform the validation downstream in the `presentation component` and then call the 'dispatchOneAction' function?

Comment: why not just define a function in the container component that validates and pass it as a prop to the presentation component?

Comment: thanks @kinakuta thats a very good suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `connect` allows a 3rd argument called `mergeProps`:

> connect([mapStateToProps], [mapDispatchToProps], [mergeProps],
>   [options])

`mergeProps` is a function that will receive the result from your `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps` and the props provided to your component. It allows you to use them all in order to manipulate and return the final props that should be applied to your component.  This could be an opportunity to decorate your action creators with additional validation logic based on your state.  You can do whatever you like, returning a completely new set of props to be applied to your component.

For example, using your described case:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ oneState, twoState }) => {
  return({
    oneState : oneState,
    twoState : twoState
  });
};

const mapDispatchToProps = ( dispatch ) => {
  return bindActionCreators({
    successAction: MyActions.successAction,
    failAction: MyActions.failAction
  }, dispatch);
};

const mergeProps = (stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) => {
  const { oneState, twoState } = stateProps;
  const { successAction, failAction } = dispatchProps;
  const validatorAction = () => {
     if (oneState && twoState) {
       successAction();
     } else {
       failAction();
     }
  } 

  return Object.assign(
    {},
    stateProps,
    // We are providing new actions props
    { validatorAction },
    ownProps        
  );
}

const C_Element = connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, mergeProps)( Ele);
```

Refer to the [official `react-redux` docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments) for more info.

---

An alternative approach is to use [`redux-thunk`](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) based actions.  This allows you to encapsulate logic within your action creators with access to the state.  You can additionally fire off further actions from within your `thunk` action.

For example:

```
function validatingAction() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { stateOne, stateTwo } = getState();

    if (stateOne && stateTwo) {
      dispatch(successAction());
    }

    dispatch(failedAction());
};
```

Comment: A problem with the `mergeProps` approach is that it is called in the `render` method of the container, which means you should not really fire actions there which change the state/props. You will get this warning: `Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition [...]`. I really like to do this in `mergeProps` though? Did you ever have this problem and found a good workaround?

Comment: Forget about my previous comment. I just have seen that you actually have a function defined which fires the actions. I assume you use it in your component which would work then. Should read more carefully. Thanks for you answer btw. :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the main benefits of separating "Containers" and "Presentational Components" is to handle all logic for a specific component inside it. That said, you might define an action that changes your state and only fire it when valid.

```
Class PresentationalComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
  onEventHandler() {
    if ( eventIsValid ) this.props.changeState();
  }
  ...
}
```

And:

```
Class ContainerComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    <PresentationalComponent changeState={actions.changeState} />
  }
}
```